# Can Bitbucket rerun pull request checks when target branch is modified?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, devops, bamboo

I am currently setting up a CI system that will check for a passing deployment against a test environment as part of a pre-merge pull request check.  This system is using Bamboo and Bitbucket, and will stop devs from merging their feature branches into the main branch if this validation fails. However, I am running into the (possibly common on my project) corner case of multiple pull requests being open at the same time, passing validation, and then being merged. In this scenario the PRs might all separately pass validation while all of them combined would break the build (I.E: PR#1 modifies a method name referenced by PR#2).

Is there a way to configure Bitbucket / Bamboo to rerun builds on pull requests if the target branch has been modified since the check last ran?

Comment: You can use several tools, there are pull request plugin, notification plugin or webhooks. Your CI could be triggered via webhook with PR's changes (target branch changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On git (bitbucket) level you could make sure to synchronize any feature or bugfix branch with an outgoing pull request by merging the latest common target branch (for example `develop`) immediately after a successful pull request merge to this target. This way you invalidate the 'latest' build result on feature or bugfix branches and they would be re-built because their git commit hash has changed. If any re-build of the feature branch fails, it won't be merged.

Ulrich

// [Izymes](https://izymes.com/) - our mission is to eliminate boring from work. We build apps that turbo-charge team velocity through contextual automation.